# Grep the count of an outlier for location

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to find the location of an outlier based on the count of the string. For instance, if I have a list of numbers between a range of 1-100 and one of the numbers is 200, if want the grep to return the place in the list where this outlier exist.

```
23
54
34
65
76
45
36
45
200
78
95
23
```

So in this case I want it to return the value "9" for the location in the list.

Comment: grep -m1 -c "Total Failed [1-9][0-9]*" outputfile_TotalPassed.txt This is what I came up with

Comment: Here, `sed -n '/.../='` or `awk '$0 > 100 {print FNR}'` would do that, but for a more general solution, you'd need to give a more precise definition of *outlier*.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and define "outlier". Grep is just a pattern matching tool, if you want it to do mathematical operations, you're looking at the wrong tool. We can help you find the right tool, but you would need to give a precise definition of what constitutes an outlier for you. As it stands, you can simply grep for lines with at least 3 characters and use `-n` (GNU `grep`) to get the line number `grep -n '...' file`.

Comment: @terdon, `-n` is standard, it's not specific to the GNU implementation of grep

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks, @StéphaneChazelas. I assumed it wasn't largely because you suggested `sed -n /.../=` instead of `grep -n` so I guessed you knew something I didn't.

Comment: `grep -n` won't easily find you a number `between a range of 1-100` as it'd have to treat `0` differently from other single digits, handle negative numbers that have fewer than 3 digits but are still outside the range, etc. Just use awk where you can clearly and simply express your needs as a value within a range of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on one possible interpretation of your requirements:

```
$ awk '!( (1 <= $1) && ($1 <= 100) ){print NR}' file
9
```